# C# network - My form(client program) doesn't show when I start server program

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, sockets, console

I'm developing a networking application.
The server program gives questions, then clients enters their answers.
Actually, both server program and client program were console program.
But, when I changed client program to Form program, It doesn't display. (ONLY WHEN I TURN ON SERVER PROGRAM!)
It works when i don't start server program.

Here's my server program code,

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server
{
    public class TaskInfo
    {
        public Socket client;
        public int thread_num;              
        public int q_num;                   

        public ManualResetEvent doneEvent;  

        public TaskInfo(Socket c, int n, int q, ManualResetEvent d)
        {
            client = c;
            thread_num = n;
            q_num = q;
            doneEvent = d;
        }
    }

    public class ServerTCP
    {
        static int num_client = 2;
        static bool[] check_co_client = new bool[num_client];
        static int num_co_client = 0;

        static void ClientHandler(Object task_info)
        {
            TaskInfo ti = (TaskInfo)task_info;

            // Casting of object
            Socket client = (Socket)ti.client;
            IPEndPoint endpoint = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;

            //Console.WriteLine("{0} connected at port {1}", endpoint.Address, endpoint.Port);

            int index = ti.q_num;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int byteRecv = 0;
            string message = "";

            string[] questions = new string[5];
            questions[0] = "0. What is 5+6?";
            questions[1] = "1. What is 1+3?";
            questions[2] = "2. What is 5+3?";
            questions[3] = "3. What is 1+1?";
            questions[4] = "4. What is 9-5?";

            string[] answers = new string[5];
            answers[0] = "11";
            answers[1] = "4";
            answers[2] = "8";
            answers[3] = "2";
            answers[4] = "4";

            try
            {
                // Send message to client
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(questions[index]);
                client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                // Receive data from client
                byteRecv = client.Receive(buffer);
                message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byteRecv);

                if (message == answers[ti.q_num])
                {
                    check_co_client[ti.thread_num] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    check_co_client[ti.thread_num] = false;
                }

                ti.doneEvent.Set();

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} [{2}:{3}]", se.ErrorCode, se.Message, endpoint.Address, endpoint.Port);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close socket
                //client.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            TcpListener listener = null;

            try
            {
                // Create new instance and start listening
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
                listener.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("<Waiting for clients connection>");

                // Accept the client connection
                Socket[] client = new Socket[num_client];
                int count = 0;
                while (count < num_client)
                {
                    client[count] = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    count++;
                }

                ManualResetEvent[] doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[num_client];

                // Start threads
                Thread[] t = new Thread[num_client];

                for (int q_num = 0; q_num < 5; q_num++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < num_client; i++)
                    {
                        doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                        TaskInfo ti = new TaskInfo(client[i], i, q_num, doneEvents[i]);

                        t[i] = new Thread(ClientHandler);
                        t[i].Start(ti);

                    }

                    WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);

                    Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    // count clients who enter correct answer
                    for (int index = 0; index < num_client; index++)
                    {
                        if (check_co_client[index])
                        {
                            num_co_client++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("number of correct answers: {0}", num_co_client);
                    num_co_client = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Code: {0}", se.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", se.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }

            Console.ReadLine(); // Pause for IDE
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my client program code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client_Form
{
    public partial class Client_Form : Form
    {
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        int count = 0;

        public Client_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Start_Program();

        }

        private void Start_Program()
        {
            try
            {
                // Connect to server
                client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8080);
                //Console.WriteLine("<Connected to server>");
                textBox.Text = "<Connected to server>";

                stream = client.GetStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                int byteRecv = 0;
                string message = "";

                int q_count = 5;

                while (count < q_count)
                {
                    while ((byteRecv = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) == 0)
                    {
                        textBox.Text = "Waiting for other client";

                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }

                    // Get data from server
                    //byteRecv = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byteRecv);

                    Co_Game_Question.Text = message;

                }

                // Close stream and connection
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

                //Console.WriteLine("<Connection closed>");
                textBox.Text = "<Connection closed>";
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", se.SocketErrorCode);
                //Console.WriteLine("Error Code: {0}", se.ErrorCode);
                //Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", se.Message);
                textBox.Text = "Error Message: " + se.Message;
            }
        }

        private void Btn_Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Send message to server
            //Console.Write("Answer {0}> ", count);
            //textBox.Text = "Answer " + count + "> ";

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(User_answer_box.Text);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            count++;
        }

    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem??
Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Calling 'Start_Program()' in the form ctor is not going to be effective - it will block the message-handling that provides the normal form functionality.  Thread off the client network code and Invoke/BeginInvoke any GUI interactions to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `NetworkStream`, fixing the client code is easy. Just switch over to the `async`/`await` idiom:

```
namespace Client_Form
{
    public partial class Client_Form : Form
    {
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        int count = 0;

        public Client_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            // Handling the network operations after the form loads ensures
            // that the asynchronous operations will come back to the main
            // thread as desired.

            // Ignore returned Task
            var _ = Start_Program();
        }

        private async void Start_Program()
        {
            try
            {
                // Connect to server
                client = await Task.Run(() => new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8080));
                textBox.Text = "<Connected to server>";

                stream = client.GetStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                int q_count = 5;

                while (count < q_count)
                {
                    textBox.Text = "Waiting for other client";

                    // Get data from server
                    int byteRecv = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byteRecv);

                    Co_Game_Question.Text = message;

                }

                // Close stream and connection
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

                textBox.Text = "<Connection closed>";
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                textBox.Text = "Error Message: " + se.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, that said, you had and still have some other bugs. First, your original code had a loop that read from the stream *until* the return value was 0. All that's going to do is consume the data in the stream without processing any of it. Very bad. I removed that bug completely in the example above.

Second, you are not checking the return value of the read. TCP guarantees only one thing: that *if* you receive any data, the bytes that you receive are in the same order in which they were sent. In particular, there are no guarantees about *how many* bytes you'll receive in any given call to `Read()`. If the remote endpoint sends 100 bytes, you could receive all 100 bytes all at once, or you could receive 1 byte at a time in 100 calls to `Read()`.

(Well, actually that's *highly* unlikely to ever happen...but it's not prohibited by the TCP contract, and in any case if you assume it's true you'll write correct code).

That's really a whole other question. The above will get your Forms program back to working, in that you'll actually be able to see the `Form` and interact with it. And the network code might even *seem* to work for awhile. But eventually you'll get a partial message, or multiple messages combined into one, or some other variation on that theme.

When that happens, IMHO one of the easiest ways to fix that in a scenario like yours is to switch to a line-based data scheme. I.e. wrap the `NetworkStream` object in `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` objects, and use the `ReadLineAsync()` method to receive data instead of the `NetworkStream.Read()` method. Regardless, feel free to post another question when you come to that bridge. :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But my program is still not working :( Actually I can see client form now, but it shows me only white form without any texts. And then I got error messages. To avoid this problem, Do I have to use ReadLineAsynce() method? I don't know your meaning that you explained "wrap the NetworkStream object in StreamReader and StreamWriter objects" (I am a beginner) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry...I have a typo in the code I posted. I forgot to switch from the `Read()` method to the `ReadAsync()` method. I'll fix the code example here; try that and if you still get errors, post a comment stating _specifically_ what the error is.